# How can I render Alarm item in FlatList with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm making a FlatList rendering Alarm items. (react-native-simple-alarm)

the tsx file where my FlatList is

```
const [alarms, setAlarms] = useState<AlarmType[]>([]);

...
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<AlarmType> = ({item}) => {
    return <ListItem props={item} />; // i have an error here on props
  };

...
  <FlatList
            ref={flatListRef}
            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
            data={alarms}
            renderItem={renderItem}  
            keyExtractor={item => item.oid} //error here on keyExtractor
          />
```

the Alarm list items that FlatList renders

```
import {Alarm as AlarmType} from 'react-native-simple-alarm/dist/Types';

const ListItem = (props: AlarmType) => {
  const deleteItem = async (oid: string | number) => {
    try {
      await deleteAlarmById(oid);

...
```

in ListItem, I also get errors saying that oid cannot be undefined.
Not sure it's because of this problem, but the time properties of alarm instances that i made in application get messed up, as I make another instances

How can I use Alarm type perfectly?? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the props incorrectly.

When you do something like

```
<ListItem props={item} />
```

You are passing props that contain a property called `props`, so in `ListItem`, the `prop` would be something like `{props: item}`.

But you want the `prop` in `ListItem` to be the `item` object, so you need to do something like

```
<ListItem {...item} />
```

To understand better, you can take a look at [the docs for ... (triple dots)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and also read [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).